# Regex for capturing paths containing keywords

Tags: regex

I have a string that looks like

`/home/user/one.jar:/home/user/two.jar:/home/user/three.jar:/home/user/four.jar`

how would I write a regex to match paths containing "two.jar" or "three.jar" so I can filter out these paths later to finally get

`home/user/one.jar:/home/user/four.jar`?

I tried `^:.*(two|three)\.jar:$` to basically say

1. Match any string that begins with `:`
2. Has any number of characters in between (to match paths like `/home/user/`
3. Match by either "two.jar" or "three.jar"
4. Ends with `:`

but I don't think I'm approaching this correctly

Comment: in your question it appears you are asking to return 'one' and 'three' but you want the result set to return 'two' and 'four'. Question reads a little confusing

Comment: I want the result to return "two" and "four" by filtering out "one" and "three" based on the names "one.jar" and "three.jar". Edited the question for clarification

Comment: Sorry updated the question to clarify. I actually want the regex to return paths containing "two" and "three" so I can filter these out later and get the final path containing only "one" and "four"

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work with

`(^|:)([^:]*(two|three)\.jar)`

Answer (score 0):

Taking this as your problem statement: `:/home/user/one.jar:/home/user/two.jar:/home/user/three.jar:/home/user/four.jar`

And this as your required solution:
`home/user/one.jar:/home/user/four.jar`

I have written this piece of regex that will help you:
`(:.+?(?:two|three)\.jar)`

This will give you

`:home/user/two.jar` in `Match 1 Group 1`

`:/home/user/three.jar` in `Match 2 Group 1`

Here is a regex101 link to the solution: https://regex101.com/r/DQMgkg/2

Hope it helped.

Comment: This will grab anything in between "one" and "four". What if I wanted to match the same paths but the given string was instead ```/home/user/zero.jar:/home/user/two.jar:/home/user/one.jar:/home/user/four.jar:/home/user/three.jar```? I need to match paths based on specific jar names, no matter how many paths are before/after/between.

Comment: Try this regex `(:?\/home\/user.?(?|one|four)\.jar)` this should do it. Here is the regex101 link: https://regex101.com/r/DQMgkg/3